# C - Referencing a function with pointers to calculate multiple times

Tags: c

I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   /* for malloc */
#include <ctype.h>

#define STD_WORK_WEEK 40
#define OVERTIME_RATE 1.5


struct employee
 {
 char first_name[10];
 char last_name[10];
 long id_number;
 float wage;
 float hours;
 float overtime;
 float gross;

 struct employee *next;
 };

 /************************************************************************/
 /*                      Function: Gross_pay_calc                        */
 /*                                                                      */
 /*  Purpose:    Calculates gross pay of an employee using hours and     */
 /*              wage data that is already stored                        */
 /*                                                                      */ 
 /*                                                                      */
 /*  Parameters: wage - Array of employee wages                          */
 /*              hours- Array of number of hours worked by an employee   */
 /*              grossPay- Gross Pay of an employee                      */
 /*              size-number of employees to process                     */
 /*                                                                      */
 /*  Returns:    Stores grossPay to be referenced in another function output  */
 /*                                                                       */
 /************************************************************************/

 /* Function call to calculate gross pay. */
 void Gross_pay_calc (struct employee *emp1)
 { 
  /*Local Variable Declaration */
  struct employee *tmp;   /* tmp pointer value to current node */



            if ( emp1->hours <= STD_WORK_WEEK ) /* Calculates grossPay based on <40 or  >40 for OT */

            {
            emp1->gross = emp1->wage*emp1->hours;
            }

            else

            {
            emp1->gross = (emp1->wage*STD_WORK_WEEK)+((emp1->hours-STD_WORK_WEEK)*     (emp1->wage*OVERTIME_RATE));
            } 

   }

   /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
   /*                                                                             */
   /* FUNCTION:  print_list                                                       */
   /*                                                                             */
   /* DESCRIPTION:  This function will print the contents of a linked             */
   /*               list.  It will traverse the list from beginning to the        */
   /*               end, printing the contents at each node.                      */
   /*                                                                             */
   /* PARAMETERS:   emp1 - pointer to a linked list                               */
   /*                                                                             */
   /* OUTPUTS:      None                                                          */
   /*                                                                             */
   /* CALLS:        None                                                          */
   /*                                                                             */
   /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
   void print_list(struct employee *emp1)
   {
    struct employee *tmp;   /* tmp pointer value to current node */
    int i = 0;              /* counts the nodes printed          */

        printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");      /*Print Header To Screen */
        printf ("     Name \t     Clock# \t Wage \t Hours \t OT \t Gross\n");
        printf ("---------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    /* Start a beginning of list and print out each value               */
    /* loop until tmp points to null (remember null is 0 or false)      */

    for(tmp = emp1; tmp ; tmp = tmp->next)
    {
        i++;

        /* TODO - print other members as well */
        printf("\n %s %s %6d %8.2f %5.2f %7.2f\n",tmp->first_name,tmp->last_name,tmp-  >id_number,
                                                  tmp->wage,tmp->hours,tmp->gross);

    }

    printf("\n\nTotal Number of Employees = %d\n", i);

   }

   /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
   /*                                                                            */
   /* FUNCTION:  main                                                            */
   /*                                                                            */
   /* DESCRIPTION:  This function will prompt the user for an employee           */
   /*               id and wage until the user indicates they are finished.      */
   /*               At that point, a list of id and wages will be                */
   /*               generated.                                                   */
   /*                                                                            */
   /* PARAMETERS:   None                                                         */
   /*                                                                            */
   /* OUTPUTS:      None                                                         */
   /*                                                                            */
   /* CALLS:        print_list                                                   */
    /*                                                                            */
   /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
   int main ()
   {

     char   answer[80];       /* to see if the user wants to add more employees */
     int    more_data = 1;    /* flag to check if another employee is to be processed */
      char   value;             /* gets the first character of answer */

struct employee *current_ptr,   /* pointer to current node */
                *head_ptr;       /* always points to first node */

   /* Set up storage for first node */
head_ptr = (struct employee *) malloc (sizeof(struct employee));
current_ptr = head_ptr;

while (more_data)
{
   /* Read in Employee ID and Hourly Wage */

    printf("\nEnter employee ID: ");
    scanf("%li", & current_ptr -> id_number);

    printf("\nEnter employee weekly wage: ");
    scanf("%f", & current_ptr -> wage);

    printf("\nEnter employee weekly hours: ");
    scanf("%f", & current_ptr -> hours);

    printf("\nEnter First Name: ");
    scanf("%s", & current_ptr -> first_name);

    printf("\nEnter Last Name: ");
    scanf("%s", & current_ptr -> last_name);

    printf("Would you like to add another employee? (y/n): ");
    scanf("%s", answer);

    Gross_pay_calc(head_ptr);

    /* Ask user if they want to add another employee */
    if ((value = toupper(answer[0])) != 'Y')
       {
       current_ptr->next = (struct employee *) NULL;
       more_data = 0; 
       }
    else
       {
       /* set the next pointer of the current node to point to the new node */
       current_ptr->next = (struct employee *) malloc (sizeof(struct employee));
      /* move the current node pointer to the new node */
       current_ptr = current_ptr->next;
       }
} /* while */

/* print out listing of all employee id's and wages that were entered */


print_list(head_ptr);

  printf("\n\nEnd of program\n");

 return 0;
   }
```

Right now, when gross_pay_calc executes, it will only calculate the first employee gross pay. How would I continue to calculate the gross_pay for every employee that I decide to add to the program?

Comment: where did you find this code **?**

Comment: First of all, fix your indentation.

Comment: I would set the last node in your linked list to null. Then you could do something like: `for(curr = head; curr != null; curr++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your code only checks the pay of the head and the head is not changing.

Simple solution would be to run gross_pay_calc on the current employee.

However I think a better way, though you would need to restructure your code, would be to write a linked list (which is basically what you have here) that instead of adding new nodes to the end, adds them to the beginning and updates the head to reflect the change.

Also, get in the habit of making more helper functions. It will make your code much easier to read and debug.